# Either Negotiate or SimpleBind must be specified and they cannot be combined

Tags: validation, active-directory, principalcontext

i am trying to validate the credentials of a user against a active directory with a principalcontext but always get an error.
I try to connect via ssl, because it is sensitive data, but it always give me the error in the headline.

```
try
{
     PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "myAwesomeDomain.com", null, ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer, adUser, adPassword);
      using (pc)
         {
             retVal = pc.ValidateCredentials(userID, password, ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer);
         }
}
```

I also tried to set DC="myAwesomeDomain,DC=COM" for the container instead of null.
The Credentials to log into the AD are correct, they are working fine with DirectoryEntry.
I have no clue how to go on.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mh, it is some time since now, i found a solution back then:

```
try
{
      using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "myAwesomeDomain.com", null, ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer, adUser, adPassword);
      {
             retVal = pc.ValidateCredentials(userID, password, ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer);
      }
}
```

it really worked this way, i can not explain why